# Can I have a Redmine database on a MySQL cluster?

Tags: redmine, mysql-cluster

I have two servers, both Debian Linux. Currently I'm using them as a poor man's load balancer for high availability. However, currently I have only 1 MySQL server on the "master", so if the master goes down then the slave is useless.

To solve this I want to setup MySQL cluster with two servers to host the Redmine database. Is this possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DRBD+Heartbeat with two servers. For MySQL cluster you will need more hardware

Comment: Is MySQL DRBD only available in MySQL Enterprise?

Comment: Is this a good tutorial? http://blog.irwan.name/?p=118